# Get Selected Text of Angular ng-option dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this drop-down list in my angular code:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
            <select class="selected_location" ng-options="perlocation.id as perlocation.name for perlocation in locations" ng-model="cleaningServiceLocation">
            <option value="">Please Select Location</option>
            </select> 
    <div>
```

Now in my controller I can easily call the selected value as:

```
$scope.cleaningServiceLocation
```

How can I get the text, or in my case, the name of the selected location?

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can mark it as answer so others know too.

Answer (score 5):

You can make model (perlocation) as object instead of (perlocation.id)-

```
<select class="selected_location" ng-options="perlocation as perlocation.name for perlocation in locations" ng-model="cleaningServiceLocation">
```

And access it as -

```
$scope.cleaningServiceLocation.name
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be to loop through the `locations` array every time the value changes and grab the `name` property from the location whose `id` matches `$scope.cleaningServiceLocation`:

```
$scope.getName = function(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.locations[i].id == id) {
      return $scope.locations[i].name;
    }
  }

  return "";
}
```

[Try it in a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XPNtdArRFXcHyqqCtgj?p=preview).