# How to get selected innetText value in select box using angular

Tags: angularjs, select

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="productList.name" ng-options="productItem.uuid as productItem.name for productItem in product.items">           
    </select>
```

**Render :**

```
<option value="prod_1">Product 1</option>
<option value="prod_2">Product 2</option>
```

When we select any option in drop down list i need to show label value like Product 1 or Product 2.

So we make at  ng-model for productList.label.

but we get "prod_1" or "prod_2"

Comment: Did you try changing the ng-options to `product.label as product.label for product in products`

Comment: @HuyHoangPham : i need to set value as my array value

Comment: Why do you need the array value? I didn't see it in the code?

Comment: @HuyHoangPham :My Html render metion like this i need to Inner TEXT Value of selected option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Selected Text of Angular ng-option dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371590/get-selected-text-of-angular-ng-option-dropdown-list)